# SOQL query on date field WHERE by year

Tags: soql

I have a custom object having a Date field Card__Date__c

I need to perform a soql query on the custom object where Card__Date__c in 2017

So my query looks like

```
List<TimeCard__c> tcList = [select id, Name from TimeCard__c where Card__Date__c = 2018 ];
```

This one is wrong. Not sure about where cause.

How do I perform this - where the year for that date field is in a fixed year ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Substitute the year with the one you want to get records for:

Documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)

```
   SELECT CreatedDate, Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = 2018
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Date startDate = date.newinstance(2017, 1, 1);
Date endDate = date.newinstance(2017, 12, 31);

List<Account> accList = [select id, name from account where CreatedDate >: startDate and CreatedDate <: endDate];
```